# CMAKE running Javascript utility

Tags: javascript, json, cmake

I'm working on a project in C/C++ buildable with cmake...
During build process I've to build configurations (headers and sources) based on some configuration file written in json format.

I reached the prefixed result adopting a script file in javascript and in the cmake I placed this command:

```
add_custom_target( BuildStructure ALL node ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/util/buildProjectStructCfg.js ...)
```

Ok, it is working fine but...

Is a portable solution?

Is it possible to try better solutions?

I adopted javascript because to handle json files for me is the best...

Comment: "Is a portable solution?" - What do you mean by "portable"? It will work on a build machine which has `node` utility installed. Assuming your script `buildProjectStructCfg.js` is "portable" too... "Is it possible to try better solutions?" - There are many other JSON parsers. Choosing from them is primary **subjective** task.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, for "portable" I mean: this idea (to run a JS utility) from cmake/make can be applied also in other platform. Currently I work in linux. Is it suitable also on windows or mac?

Comment: "Is it suitable also on windows or mac?" - Which "suitability" you are asking about?  According to [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download), Node.js is available on Windows and Mac. So you (as a project's developer) may ask users of your project to install Node.js before building your project. If you ask whether users will be happy with such requirement, then it is mostly subjective.

Comment: Your considerations are consistent. For sure choose to run a JS procedure (requiring the node installation) is annoying for a new installation of the environment... The problem is: what other solution can I choose?
You mentioned "there are many other parsers...". The problem is that CMake is a force of nature but not for JS handling...
I also was thinking about converting the JSON to XML or YAML format and then?
Some other utilities are necessary...
Instead what I would like is: git clone, cmake, make...

Comment: CMake has its own interface for parsing JSON: [string(JSON)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#json). This interface could be suitable for extracting one or two values from json file, but it could be inconvenient for complex parsing. Otherwise you are free to choose any separate JSON parser. That choice is primarily **subjective**: that is, there is no "best tool" for that purpose and asking for such best tool has no sense. (And prohibited on Stack Overflow: [help/on-topic]).